# Rails cannot connect to mySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, apache

I have been trying to set up an Apache server utilizing Ruby on Rails and mySQL through Phusion Passenger. I have Apache v2.2.3, Passenger v3.0.13, Ruby v1.9.3, Rails v3.2.6, and mySQL v5.0.95.

Earlier, I encountered problems due to an incorrect Javascript runtime, but I was able to fix that by installing execjs and therubyracer. I was successfully able to create the website with SQLite, but I need to use mySQL instead.

Now, I have created a new project with the command "rails new myProject -d mysql" and added the appropriate gems to my Gemfile (that is, "gem 'mysql2','0.3.11'"; "gem 'execjs'"; and "gem 'therubyracer'").

My database.yml file looks like this (the test and production parts only differ in terms of name) :

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: myProject_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Now, the problem is not immediately apparent. From terminal, I cannot find any problems (that is, "rake db:create" runs correctly, no errors appear upon scaffolding, etc.), but when I visit the website, Passenger displays the following error:

### Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

#### Could not find mysql2-0.3.11 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

And none of the webpages appear. So, where is my fault? I believe my Gemfile is correct, my database.yml seems to be updated, I can access mySQL from terminal, and I was able to run the website in SQLite. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

EDIT: My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2','0.3.11'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server                     
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

EDIT: Output of "bundle list":

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.6)
  * actionpack (3.2.6)
  * activemodel (3.2.6)
  * activerecord (3.2.6)
  * activeresource (3.2.6)
  * activesupport (3.2.6)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.1.4)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-rails (2.0.2)
  * json (1.7.3)
  * libv8 (3.3.10.4)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.19)
  * multi_json (1.3.6)
  * mysql2 (0.3.11)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.6)
  * railties (3.2.6)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * sass (3.1.20)
  * sass-rails (3.2.5)
  * sprockets (2.1.3)
  * therubyracer (0.10.1)
  * thor (0.15.4)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.33)
  * uglifier (1.2.6)
```

EDIT: Oh, and I'm working off of **CentOS 5.8**, by the way.

Comment: Did you run `bundle` after adding the `mysql2` gem?

Comment: Try to execute `bundle update`

Comment: I added my Gemfile to the original post. And, thanks, but I have run "bundle update" or "bundle install" after every edit (along with "service httpd restart"). I see all the gems I installed when I run bundle, and it shows the correct mysql2 (0.3.11) version.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Next run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: It contains mysql2 (0.3.11). I don't know what else you would be looking for, but just in case, I've appended it to my post. Thanks.